# distance between two points google maps a is undefined api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Updating to v3. 
Library is declared like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Finding distance like this:

```
var loc1 = google.maps.LatLng(52.5773139, 1.3712427);
var loc2 = google.maps.LatLng(52.4788314, 1.7577444);
alert(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (loc1, loc2));
```

Firebug returns this:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

Assuming it's an error because lat and lon need to be passed as objects, so after some googling I tried this:

```
var loc1 = google.maps.LatLng({'position' :52.5773139, 1.3712427});
var loc2 = google.maps.LatLng({'position' :52.4788314, 1.7577444});
```

Still get same error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the `new`-operator before `google.maps.LatLng` is missing

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have gotten the *same* error when you tried that strange code you found "after some googling". That code has a syntax error and would not run at all. In fact, I'm curious to know what site suggested such a thing! Google has excellent documentation on the Maps API - reference, tutorials, examples. The docs are a great place to start for your next Maps API question instead of random googling. You can even google "maps api" to find them. :-)

Comment: If the guys at Google were worth their salt, they would make all their classes instantiate properly regardless of whether `new` is used or not. The coding is simple and [well documented](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/#postcomment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the keyword `new` to instantiate the `LatLng` object.

```js
var loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5773139, 1.3712427);
var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4788314, 1.7577444);
```